# RStudio contour function not displaying a plot

Tags: r, rstudio, data-visualization

I'm using RStudio and for some reason I am not getting any output plot using contour function.
This is what I'm trying

> x<-seq(1,10)
>
> y<-x
>
> f<-outer(x,y,function(x,y)cos(y)/(1+x^2))
>
> contour(x,y,f)

I don't know if it is because of some missing package or the version of R i'm using.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Graphics are OS-dependent and you are not giving that information. I cannot reproduce you problem on a Mac running R 3.3.3. RStudio might be the problem if you do not know how to use it. It has a lot of output hiding buttons and tabs. What happens if you first open a graphics window or perhaps try writing to a file?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I tried updating the RStudio and installed version 1.0.136 and it worked. I can now visualize my data using contour and image functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dev.off() and wait for null devices. This worked for me.